# What are the reactions at the supports?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, statics

Suppose that you have a bar of length 2 meters. This bar is along the x-axis. At x=0 there is a pin support. Also, at x=1 meter there is a pin support. A forceof magnitude 50Newtons is applied along the x-axis or along the axis of the bar at x=2 meters. What are the reactions at the supports?

Comment: Is this a cantilever beam - ie no support at 2 meters?

Comment: @AsymLabs Yes there is no support at 2 meters

Comment: Consider that, for static equilibrium, the sum of the moments at X=1m must equal zero, and that the sum of the forces at all points must also equal zero.  Then by substitution of forces, ie F0, F1 and 50 you can arrive at the correct solution for the reactions at x=0 and x=1.

Comment: @AsymLabs I think I must correct the question.. The applied force is along the x - axis

Comment: That changes the problem considerably.  In this case, if the loading is perfectly along the x axis, and there is no bending, does F0 carry any load?

Comment: In other words, if the load passes directly through the pin at 1, the pin at support 0 could be removed and you would still have perfect static equilibrium.

Comment: @AsymLabs Why does this scenario (F1=50 Newtons and F0=0)occur? I mean If F0 carries 25 Newtons and F1 carries 25 Newtons, static equilibrium is also satisfied

Comment: We are ignoring the effects of the materials, friction, bending, strain, movement etc. So as you have described the arrangement as an idealized one then the entire force would be taken by the pin at x=1, as I see it.  There would be no reason for the load to transfer to the pin at x=0.  You could remove it entirely and it will have no effect on the static equilibrium.

Comment: With an idealized scenario, what would cause any load to be carried by the pin at x=0?  There is no reason for the load to transfer to it to gain static equilibrium.  Of course once the load deviates from the pure x-axis direction then a moment is introduced and this would require the load to be distributed between the pins.  But as long as the load is directed exactly along the x axis and through the pins then there is no reason for the pin at x=0 to carry any load.

Comment: You should show how you have analysed this so far - this is not a “we do your (home)work site”...

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.